# normalize response in reducer got type error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I use redux and failed to do a map to turn my UTC date into a proper format using moment.

```
const adsReducer = (state = initalState, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_ADS_PENDING':
      return { ...state, loading: true }
    case 'FETCH_ADS_FULFILLED':
      return { 
        ...state, 
        loading: false, 
        data: ((action.payload || {}).data || {}).map(o => ({...o, created_at: moment(o.created_at).format('DD-MM-YYYY')})),
      }
   }
}
```

If I simply return action.payload.data then it will be fine, but I want to parse the date to a proper format, above code cause an error like this

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: ((action.payload || (intermediate value)).data || (intermediate value)).map is not a function
```

any clue what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) available on array only..

Use default value to `[]` instead of `{}`

```
data: ((action.payload || []).data || []).
map(o => ({...o, created_at: moment(o.created_at).format('DD-MM-YYYY')})),
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to map over an object, if `action.payload` is not defined or `action.payload.data` is not defined

Assuming `action.payload.data` is an array you could do the following:

```
action.payload && 
    action.payload.data && 
        action.payload.data.map(o => (
           {...o, created_at: moment(o.created_at)
                              .format('DD-MM-YYYY')
            }
        )),
```

Comment: I use `(action.payload || {})` isn't that the same with using `&&` ?

Comment: should be `((action.payload || {}).data || [])` in that case